# Exposing python jupyter on LAN

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, ubuntu-14.04, jupyter

I've installed jupyter on local network LAN but im unable to access `http://<IP>:8888` from another macine on LAN. I've opened ports 8888 and port range 49152 to 65535 with iptables (this range is specified at http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/public_server.html)

This guide http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/public_server.html describes exposing a notebook publicly but I'm just attempting to share over LAN.

Have I missed a step ?

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Try `jupyter notebook --ip <your_LAN_ip> --port 8888`
Then visit `http://your_LAN_ip:8888` from another computer.

It's recommended that you use a password when accessing your notebook server. To set up a password, just run `jupyter notebook password`. To make it even more secure, you can use SSL for your server by passing the arguments `--certfile` and `--keyfile` to `jupyter notebook`. You can read more about setting that up [here](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/public_server.html#notebook-server-security).

Comment: It should be possible to set this as a setting in a configuration file rather than using a command line argument. It would be something like: run the command which creates the default settings file, find the setting in there and set it correctly.

Comment: Also: I assume `ip` here is the ip address of the Jupyter host, not the client connecting to it? Otherwise, only a single machine would be able to talk to the Jupyer host (server). That would be very odd.

Answer (score 16):

### In macOS, the following worked for me

#### 0. Generate configure file using

`jupyter notebook --generate-config`

#### 1. Set in configure file and add

```
c.NotebookApp.ip = '0.0.0.0' # listen on all IPs
c.NotebookApp.token = ''     # disable authentication
c.NotebookApp.allow_origin = '*' # allow access from anywhere
c.NotebookApp.disable_check_xsrf = True # allow cross-site requests
```

#### 2. Run:

```
jupyter notebook --ip <your_LAN_ip> --port 8888
```

Comment: Port number can be added to the configuration as well using the following:
`c.NotebookApp.port = 8888`

Answer (score 8):

It's also possible to add the IP/host in the configuration file in the `c.NotebookApp.ip = '<your_ip_or_hostname>'` and `c.NotebookApp.port = 8888` parameters.

If you don't have a jupyter configuration file yet run `jupyter notebook --generate-config`